# Git Push Error: Permission to Petrie/CommonJavascriptLib.git denied to sxfszwr/wudangpai.

Tags: git, github

I clone a new respo use:

```
git clone git@github.com:Petrie/CommonJavascriptLib.git
```

when I update some code,  I run "git push origin master", then errors:

```
$ git push origin master  
ERROR: Permission to Petrie/CommonJavascriptLib.git denied to sxfszwr/wudangpai.  
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  

Please make sure you have the correct access rights  
and the repository exists.
```

who can tell me why ? 
and I change the remote url:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/Petrie/CommonJavascriptLib.git
```

push command works!
But I don't know why! who can explain me, thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be in ssh key.
https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey (read last point "Verify the public key is attached to your GitHub account")